# How to convert string to LPWSTR in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can anyone help in converting `string` to `LPWSTR`

```
string command=obj.getInstallationPath()+"<some string appended>"
```

Now i wat to pass it as parameter for `CreateProcessW(xx,command,x...)`

But `createProcessW()` accepts only `LPWSTR` so i need to cast `string` to `LPWSTR`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcwstr-in-c-unicode

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: this question is wider than the one you refer to.

Answer (score 13):

If you have an ANSI string, then have you considered calling `CreateProcessA` instead? If there is a specific reason you need to call `CreateProcessW` then you will need to convert the string. Try the [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 6):

Another way:

```
mbstowcs_s
```

use with string.c_str(), you can find example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6858585/823640)

OR

```
USES_CONVERSION_EX;

std::string text = "text";
LPWSTR lp = A2W_EX(text.c_str(), text.length());
```

OR

```
{
    std::string str = "String to LPWSTR";
    BSTR b = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR(str.c_str());
    LPWSTR lp = b;
    Use lp before SysFreeString...
    SysFreeString(b);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same thing as in @gbjbaanb's answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1198822/6610

Comment: I had to change it a little to get it working :
CComBSTR bstrDomain(csDomain);
LPWSTR pszServerName = bstrDomain;
NetWkstaGetInfo(pszServerName,dwLevel,(LPBYTE *)&pBuf);

Comment: `SysFreeString` deallocates the memory, you cannot use `lp` afterwards

Comment: @MattMcNabb added your consideration.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to convert an ansi string to a  wide (unicode) string is to use the [string conversion macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn059-using-mfc-mbcs-unicode-conversion-macros?view=msvc-160#generic-conversion-macros).

To use these, put USES_CONVERSION at the top of your function, then you can use macros like A2W() to perform the conversion very easily.

eg.

```
char* sz = "tadaaa";
CreateProcessW(A2W(sz), ...);
```

The macros allocate space on the stack, perform the conversion and return the converted string.

Comment: The documentation you refer to also says you don't need the USES_CONVERSION for ATL7.0 and up.

Comment: yeah, but I've been using it for so long I add that automatically :)

Answer (score 2):

Also, you might want to consider using `TCHAR` throughout... If I'm correct, the idea would be something like this:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring

// Make any methods you control return tstring values. Thus, you could write:
tstring command = obj.getInstallationPath();
CreateProcess(x, command.c_str(), ...);
```

Note that we use `CreateProcess` instead of `CreateProcessW` or `CreateProcessA`. The idea is that if `UNICODE` is defined, then `TCHAR` is `typedef`ed to `WCHAR` and `CreateProcess` is `#define`d to be `CreateProcessW`, which accepts a `LPWSTR`; but if `UNICODE` is not defined, then `TCHAR` becomes `char`, and `CreateProcess` becomes `CreateProcessA`, which accepts a `LPSTR`. But I might not have the details right here... this stuff seems somewhat needlessly complicated :(.

Comment: Agreed, I always use tchar for this kind of thing.

Comment: Only use TCHAR for converting ancient windows software. The only ones having good reason to keep using it are microsoft documentation writers, when they have both an A and a W function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option. I've been using this function to do the conversion.

```
//C++ string to WINDOWS UNICODE string
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
   int len;
   int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
   len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
   wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
   MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
   std::wstring r(buf);
   delete[] buf;
   return r;
}
```

And wrap your string like this.
   s2ws( volume.c_str())

Comment: If that has an exception, it will create a memory leak.

Comment: @Jonathan The memory leak can be fixed by using `std::vector<wchar_t> buf(len);` instead of the `new` line.

Comment: also there is a problem that if `s.size() > INT_MAX - 1` you'll get bogus results at best ; to make this function robust it should check for that and throw an exception or take some other well-defined action