# Convert char * to LPWSTR

Tags: c++, c, string

I am trying to convert a program for multibyte character to Unicode.

I have gone through the program and preceded the string literals with `L` so they look like `L"string"`.

This has worked but I am now left with a C style string that won't conform. I have tried the `L` and putting it in `TEXT()` but the `L` gets added to the variable name -- not the string -- if I use `TEXT()`.

I have tried making it a `TCHAR` but then it complains that it cannot convert a `TCHAR` to a `char *`.

What options am I left with?

I know C and C++ are different. It is an old in-house C library that has been used in C++ projects for several years now.

Comment: The main reason why someone would downvote would more be, imho, the lack of source code in your question. An image is worth a thousand words, and so does a piece of code. Even a trivial one.

Comment: You can definitely write code that works with `TCHAR` no matter what the compiler setting, you just have to create the right infrastructure. In C++, overloading does all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert char\* to LPCWSTR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715144/how-to-convert-char-to-lpcwstr)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The [`std::mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) function is what you are looking for:

```
 char text[] = "something";
 wchar_t wtext[20];
 mbstowcs(wtext, text, strlen(text)+1);//Plus null
 LPWSTR ptr = wtext;
```

for `string`s,

```
 string text = "something";
 wchar_t wtext[20];
 mbstowcs(wtext, text.c_str(), text.length());//includes null
 LPWSTR ptr = wtext;
```

--> ED: The "L" prefix only works on string literals, not variables. <--

Comment: that's deprecated, you should use `mbstowcs_s()`

Comment: @Olipro: This is "deprecated" only in the Windows world. The OP did not stated which platform he was targeting.

Comment: it's fairly implicit that the platform is Windows, but if you think otherwise, go ahead and prove me wrong.

Comment: @Olipro: what's the advantage of the `_s` versions? As far as I can tell, you pass another count parameter that indicates at most how many characters you want written out, but how does that help? You already specify the size of the output buffer in another argument, is this just for the sake of the terminating zero?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it is only possible to convert `char*` to `LPWSTR` if the length of the `char*` is known? If not, why was the assumption, that 20 characters will suffice, made?

Answer (score 12):

The clean way to use `mbstowcs` is to call it twice to find the length of the result:

```
  const char * cs = <your input char*>
  size_t wn = mbsrtowcs(NULL, &cs, 0, NULL);

  // error if wn == size_t(-1)

  wchar_t * buf = new wchar_t[wn + 1]();  // value-initialize to 0 (see below)

  wn = mbsrtowcs(buf, &cs, wn + 1, NULL);

  // error if wn == size_t(-1)

  assert(cs == NULL); // successful conversion

  // result now in buf, return e.g. as std::wstring

  delete[] buf;
```

Don't forget to call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` at the beginning of your program!

The advantage over the Windows `MultiByteToWideChar` is that this is entirely standard C, although on Windows you might prefer the Windows API function anyway.

I usually wrap this method, along with the opposite one, in two conversion functions `string`->`wstring` and `wstring`->`string`. If you also add trivial overloads `string`->`string` and `wstring`->`wstring`, you can easily write code that compiles with the Winapi `TCHAR` typedef in any setting.

[*Edit:*] I added zero-initialization to `buf`, in case you plan to use the C array directly. I would usually return the result as `std::wstring(buf, wn)`, though, but do beware if you plan on using C-style null-terminated arrays.[/]

In a multithreaded environment you should pass a thread-local conversion state to the function as its final (currently invisible) parameter.

Here is a [small rant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) of mine on this topic.

Comment: +1 for showing how to call the function twice to get the length of the output buffer

Comment: Cheers. In the privacy of my own thoughts, I actually use a variable-length array for `buf`, but I wanted to avoid that in the light of SO scrutiny :-)

Comment: Update: nowadays I would look for [`codecvt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt), which wraps `mbsrtowcs`/`wcsrtombs`.

Answer (score 5):

This version, using the Windows API function `MultiByteToWideChar()`, handles the memory allocation for arbitrarily long input strings.

```
int lenA = lstrlenA(input);
int lenW = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, input, lenA, NULL, 0);
if (lenW>0)
{
    output = new wchar_t[lenW];
    ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, input, lenA, output, lenW);
}
```

Comment: @Kerrek In the interests of brevity I omitted the code that calls `free`  ;-)

Comment: I'd rather you leave it as it is than call `free()`! This is definitely a case for the celebrated `delete[]` expression :-)

Comment: @kerrek Indeed! It's so hard to keep track of C and C++ going from question to question.

Comment: It seems there is no need in 'lstrlenA(input)' call. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072.aspx). _cbMultiByte : Size, in bytes, of the string indicated by the lpMultiByteStr parameter. Alternatively, this parameter can be set to -1 if the string is null-terminated._ Just use -1 instead of lenA.

Comment: @Alan it could be done that way but on the other hand this way means the length is calculated once rather than twice. Personal choice I guess.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the following in VC++ and it works like a charm for me.

```
CA2CT(charText)
```

Comment: remember to include for that macro #include <atlstr.h>

Answer (score 2):

You may use `CString`, `CStringA`, `CStringW` to do automatic conversions and convert between these types. Further, you may also use `CStrBuf`, `CStrBufA`, `CStrBufW` to get RAII pattern modifiable strings

Comment: Note, however, that they are ATL/MFC specific.

Comment: @JBES, Yes they are. I answered it 6+ year ago where ATL/MFC was largely used. Now, even the C++ language has library features for conversions.