# How can I convert from ANSI character (char) to Unicode character (wchar_t) and vice versa?

Tags: c++, char, wchar-t

How can I convert from ANSI character (char) to Unicode character (wchar_t) and vice versa?

Is there any cross-platform source code for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in `<cstdlib>` you have `mbstowcs()` and `wcstombs()`.

I've previously posted [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858524/convert-char-to-lpwstr/6858692#6858692) on how to use this, maybe that's helpful. Make sure you run the function twice, once to get the length and once to do the actual conversion. (Here's a little [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) of what the functions mean.) Instead of the manual char array, I would probably prefer a `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<wchar_t>`, coming to think of it.

Note that `wchar_t` has nothing to do with Unicode. If you need Unicode, you need to further convert from `wchar_t` to Unicode using a separate library (like `iconv()`), and don't use `wchar_t` as the data type for Unicode codepoints. Instead, use `uint32_t` on legacy systems or `char32_t` on modern ones.

Comment: Thanks, But these functions are for string conversion.

Comment: There's an equivalent `mbtowc()` and `wctomb()` for single characters.

Comment: @Amir you can use them to convert a string of one character length to another string of one character length and exract the character.

Comment: If not string how does a 16 bit wchar_t convert in to one 8 but char?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this works, I don't know if it will always work or if it's a coincidence, but I thought it was worth showing:

```
const char* c = "hey yo";
wstring s(c, c + 6);

wcout << s << endl;
wcin.get();
```

prints

```
hey yo
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at libraries like [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion) and [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/) if you really are using Unicode and not just 16 bit characters. That is Unicode does not just deal with single characters not even 16 bit ones as plain wchar_t does.