# How to convert char* to LPCWSTR?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I know this has already been discussed in several questions on SO, but none of those solutions have worked for me.

I start with a `char*` because this is for a DLL that will be called from VBA, and `char*` is necessary for VBA to pass a string to the DLL.

I need to return a `LPCWSTR` because that's the input parameter for the API function I'm trying to call, and I can't enable casting by switching from Unicode to multi-byte character set in the Properties window, because the API has this code:

```
#if !defined(UNICODE) && !defined(NOUNICODE)
#error UNICODE is not defined. UNICODE must be defined for correct API arguments.
#endif
```

I tried this:

```
LPCWSTR convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(char* charArray)
    {
        const char* cs=charArray;
        wchar_t filename[4096] = {0};
        MultiByteToWideChar(0, 0, cs[1], strlen(cs[1]), filename, strlen(cs[1]));
    }
```

which gave these errors:

```
error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char' to 'const char *'
error C2664: 'MultiByteToWideChar' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const char' to 'LPCCH'
```

I tried this (same function header), loosely adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6858692/619177):

```
size_t retVal;
const char * cs = charArray;    
size_t length=strlen(cs);
wchar_t * buf = new wchar_t[length]();  // value-initialize to 0 (see below)
size_t wn = mbsrtowcs_s(&retVal,buf,20, &cs, length + 1, NULL);
return buf;
```

This compiled ok, but when I passed it an example string of "xyz.xlsx", `mbsrtowcs_s()` set `buf` to an empty string: `L""`

So, how do I make this conversion?

Comment: MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, cs, -1, filename, 4096);

Comment: Why don't you make the function take a const char* and avoid the pointless pointer copying. Do you really mean to skip the first char? Why don't you use warring for the conversion?

Comment: @HansPassant, this works, but when I try to handle several char* in a row, e.g. `LPCWSTR str1=convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(str1);LPCWSTR str2=convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(str2);` then the second pointer gets assigned to the same address as the first pointer (i think), because both `LPCWSTR` end up with the same value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, how do I use "warring" for the conversion?  I googled that but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Sure, that happens when you write illegal C code.  You can't return a pointer to a local variable.  You struggling with the very basics of C, you really do need to start at "Hello world" and do all the exercises.

Comment: Sorry. Auto correct fail. My bad. It is wstring.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for the encouragement.  I've been reading about pointers and trying to figure out how to preserve the value referenced by the pointer once it goes out of scope.  I tried passing in a `wchar_t` parameter so that the pointer could reference that instead of a local variable, but that didn't work.  How can I keep that value outside of the function?

Comment: @HansPassant, ok, I think I got it, answer posted below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert char \* to LPWSTR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858524/convert-char-to-lpwstr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `cs` is a `const char*`, `cs[1]` is a `const char`.  C++ won't convert it to a pointer for you, because in most cases that doesn't make sense.

You could instead say `&cs[1]` or `cs+1` if the intent is to skip the first char.  (That's what you're doing when you pass a pointer to the 1th element; in C++, indexes start at 0.)   If the intent is to pass the whole string, then just pass `cs`.

Answer (score 20):

Following Hans Passant's advice regarding pointers to local variables, I worked out this approach, which seems to work well:

```
wchar_t *convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
{
    wchar_t* wString=new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
}
```

I'm aware that the use of `new` requires memory management, which I perform in the function that calls this one.

Comment: Yup, that works. Well, as long as the string isn't bigger than 4096 characters. You can fix that too, read the docs.  Using std::wstring as a return value is the next step ahead.

Comment: Best solution. Thanks