# Get all files listed inside .exe directory not knowing location

Tags: c++, winapi, directory

I guess my question is this - How would I get the directory of the exe location as an LPCWSTR so that I can input it into my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA a;
HANDLE swap = FindFirstFile(/*(LPCWSTR)__exe_directory__*/,&a);
if (swap!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        char *sptn = new char [lstrlen(a.cFileName)+1];
        for (int c=0;c<lstrlen(a.cFileName);c++)
        {
            sptn[c]=char(a.cFileName[c]);
        }
        sptn[lstrlen(a.cFileName)]='\0';
        std::cout<<sptn<<std::endl;
    }
    while (FindNextFile(swap,&a));
}
else std::cout<<"undetected file\n";
FindClose(swap);
system("pause");
}
```

And it would return the listed files in the directory without error. I know for a fact that my code already works given the directory, I tested it already.

Comment: I suppose using [`GetModuleFileNameW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) and a little trimming is out of the question?

Comment: I tried getmodulefilenamew ... what do you mean by a little trimming, please care to elaborate? When I put it in there `GetModuleFileNameW(NULL,sptn,MAX_PATH)` -- first of all, it's not an LPCWSTR, and when I type cast it, it returns the number 78 as output?

Comment: Can't you create it using argv[0] and PATH?

Comment: @Jim I'm just working in this int main(...) environment for testing of the functions that I am creating, then I just copy and paste it into my main project. Given that the function in my main project is a void(), how would I go about using argv[0]? Even then, __argv[0] is the same as argv[0] if you can't specify the arguments in a main function, but in any case again typecasting returns the same number 78, and it's not an LPCWSTR in the first place.

Comment: To convert the narrow string to a wide string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715144/how-to-convert-char-to-lpcwstr

Comment: So how exactly would I do it in my circumstance?

Comment: Check the first answer to that question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647429/c-windows-path-to-the-folder-where-the-executable-is-located

Comment: @RamiHelmy  After implementing that routine I get this error in the console `>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathRemoveFileSpecW@4 referenced in function "wchar_t * __cdecl GetThisPath(wchar_t *,unsigned int)" (?GetThisPath@@YAPA_WPA_WI@Z)`

And by that routine I mean the 2nd answer to the question with GetDestPath()

Comment: Silly me. I see the commented out `/*(LPCWSTR)__exe_directory__*/` and naturally assume that meant something at some point. Regardless, use the narrow version instead , i.e. `GetModuleFileNameA`

Comment: Try this: Set the "Treat wchar_t as Built-in Type" option to "No" (specify /Zc:wchar_t- on the compiler command line)

Comment: I need a permanent solution, the solution can't mix up my other functions... this isn't my only function, i have about 300 other functions that use the same methods. I need a solution that only goes for this function specifically. Anyone?

Comment: I've removed the [c] and [visual-studio] spurious tags.

Comment: @user3267146: To fix the linker error, you can use a proper `#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to use [**`GetModuleFileName()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (passing `nullptr` as module handle, to refer to current process EXE), and then call [**`PathRemoveFileSpec()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or `PathCchRemoveFileSpec()`, if you don't care about Windows versions prior to Windows 8) to strip the file spec from the path.

To use `PathRemoveFileSpec()` you must link with Shlwapi.lib, as stated in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

See this compilable code as an example:

```
#include <iostream>     // For console output
#include <exception>    // For std::exception
#include <stdexcept>    // For std::runtime_error
#include <string>       // For std::wstring
#include <Windows.h>    // For Win32 SDK
#include <Shlwapi.h>    // For PathRemoveFileSpec()

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

// Represents an error in a call to a Win32 API.
class win32_error : public std::runtime_error 
{
public:
    win32_error(const char * msg, DWORD error) 
        : std::runtime_error(msg)
        , _error(error)
    { }

    DWORD error() const 
    {
        return _error;
    }

private:
    DWORD _error;
};

// Returns the path without the filename for current process EXE.
std::wstring GetPathOfExe() 
{
    // Get filename with full path for current process EXE
    wchar_t filename[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD result = ::GetModuleFileName(
        nullptr,    // retrieve path of current process .EXE
        filename,
        _countof(filename)
    );
    if (result == 0) 
    {
        // Error
        const DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
        throw win32_error("Error in getting module filename.", 
                          error);
    }

    // Remove the file spec from the full path
    ::PathRemoveFileSpec(filename);

    return filename;
}

int main() 
{
    try 
    {
        std::wcout << "Path for current EXE:\n"
                   << GetPathOfExe() 
                   << std::endl;
    } 
    catch (const win32_error & e) 
    {
        std::cerr << "\n*** ERROR: " << e.what()
                  << " (error code: " << e.error() << ")" 
                  << std::endl;
    } 
    catch (const std::exception& e) 
    {
        std::cerr << "\n*** ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In console:

> ```
> C:\Temp\CppTests>cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE get_exe_path.cpp
> get_exe_path.cpp
>
> C:\Temp\CppTests>get_exe_path.exe
> Path for current EXE:
> C:\Temp\CppTests
> ```

---

**PS**
In your code, you seem to refer to the Unicode version of `FindFirtFile()` (i.e. `FindFirstFileW()`, since in the comment you expect a `LPCWSTR`, i.e. `const wchar_t*`), but then in the following code you use ANSI/MBCS strings (i.e. `char*`).

I'd suggest you to always use **Unicode** UTF-16 `wchar_t*` strings in modern Windows C++ code: it's better for internationalization, and modern Win32 APIs only come with a Unicode version.

Note also that, since you are using C++, it's better to use a robust convenient **string class** (e.g. `std::wstring` for Unicode UTF-16 strings with Microsoft Visual C++), instead of C-like raw character pointers. Use the raw pointers at the API interface (since the Win32 API has a C interface), and then safely convert to a `std::wstring`.

Comment: By the way, if I may ask. I am not familiar with this "age" of c++, C++13? When you refer `::PathRemoveFileSpec(filename);` -- which namespace are you pointing it to? How are you able to just write it out like that? Doesn't make sense to me. Is it just taking standard by default?

Comment: `PathRemoveFileSpec()` is a pure C-interface Win32 API function. It belongs to the "global namespace", and I have the habit of prefixing Win32 C APIs with `::` (this can be useful e.g. when you are inside a C++ class that may have a method named like a Win32 API function, so with `::` you clearly identify the "global" Win32 C-interface API function).

Comment: Ah, hmmm, thanks for the tip then, I will be sure to apply it to my code. On a side note, you state that FindFirstFileW() requires the wchar_t* for the LPCWSTR but when I add the GetPathOfExe() function as parameter one it says there is no suitable conversion from std::wstring to LPCWSTR. What are my alternatives to get around this?

Comment: `std::wstring` doesn't have an implicit conversion operator to `LPCWSTR` (unlike `CString`). An alternative is to call `std::wstring::c_str()` member function, which returns a `const wchar_t*` (i.e. a `LPCWSTR`).

Comment: Two things, first of all, how would I put the std::wstring::c_str() into the getpathofexe() function since that is the function where the typecasting conversion error results. Also, I feel as if I am very "outdated" with all this modern C++ jibber jabber. I was programming in C all my life (which only constricts to 6 years). Now when I come onto these new generation forums I feel very saddened by all these new functions people are throwing at me which I have never even heard of. Do you think it would be possible if you could recommend me a C++ book for C Programmers that can enlighten me? :)

Comment: @user3267146: If there is a place where you need a `LPCWSTR`, just do `GetPathOfExe().c_str()` and you get the required raw C-like string pointer. Sorry I don't know of any _"C++ book for C Programmers"_...

Answer (score 3):

Use the [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) function, in  an UNICODE build, to obtain the executable full file name in a wide string.

Then, search for the last '\' character and replace it by 0.

Done.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
    wchar_t szExeFullPath[ MAX_PATH ];
    if ( GetModuleFileName( NULL, szExeFullPath, _countof( szExeFullPath ) ) ) {
        wchar_t * pszLastAntiSlash = wcsrchr( szExeFullPath, L'\\' );
        if ( pszLastAntiSlash ) {
            *pszLastAntiSlash = 0;
            wprintf( L"Exe full path is %s\n", szExeFullPath );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```