# Deleting a file in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I just recently got into C++, and I wanted to make something simple to start off with. I made a console program that asks the user for a file path and then deletes the file. However, I've encountered a problem I cannot seem to resolve or find a solution for. The statement `DeleteFile(filePath.c_str());` is giving me 2 errors:

> argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
>
> 'BOOL DeleteFileW(LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const_Elem*' to 'LPCWSTR'

First of all, I need to convert `std::string` to `LPCWSTR`, so I added `c_str()` in the end which gave me those 2 errors.

I'm still a noob in C++ so go easy on me.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>

int main() 
{
    loop:
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    std::string filePath;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h,15);
    std::cout << "\nEnter the path of the file you'd like to remove: ";

    if (!std::getline(std::cin, filePath)) { std::cout << "I/O error!"; }

    while (true)
    {
        if (!filePath.empty())
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(h,15);
            std::cout << "[+] Checking if file exists";
            std::ifstream ifile(filePath);
            if (ifile) 
            {
                std::cout << "\n[!] File exists!";
                std::cout << "\n[#] Deleting file";
                DeleteFile(filePath);
                std::ifstream ifile(filePath);
                if (!ifile) 
                {
                    std::cout << "\n[!] File deleted successfully!";
                }
                else 
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                    std::cout << "\n[!] Failed to delete file";
                }
                goto loop;
            }
            else 
            {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                std::cout << "\nPlease enter a valid file path!";
                goto loop;
            }

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid file path!";
            goto loop;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\nFile deleted!";
}
```

Comment: If you are compiling on one operating system only (Windows in your case?), please include the information in the question and add the corresponding tags. Different OSes have different filesystem APIs.

Comment: The `DeleteFile` function takes an argument of either `const wchar_t *` or `const char *` depending on whether your project is configured for use of Unicode or not. If you have Unicode selected, you should change your `std::string` to `std::wstring`, or use the explicit `DeleteFileA` function (always takes `const char *`).

Comment: Also, even if you're just learning... Or rather, especialy since you're just learning: do not use `goto`! It has its places I suppose (less so in C++ where there are exceptions), but do not get into the habit of using it like this! Doesn't the compiler warn you about this anyway? Try increasing warning level... `/W4` might be good when you are learning.

Comment: If you "recently got into C++", then you should be working with a good C++ book. There are many C++ topics and skills that need to be learned -- classes, methods, multiple and virtual inheritance, templates, containers, execution threads and many more -- that are far more important to understand thoroughly, than learning how to implement basic operating system-specific tasks. Don't get off the track, but continue to read and follow along your C++ book. You have plenty of things to learn for, oh, 3-5 years or so, before running out of material and moving on to these kind of things...

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica When I make my filePath an std::wstring, `if(!std::getline(std::cin, filePath))` tells me `no instance of overloaded function "std::getline" matches the argument list`. If I change DeleteFile to DeleteFileA, it still doesn't delete the file for some reason?

Comment: OK, so the second method (using `DeleteFileA`) 'nearly' works! Probably (just a wild guess) you need to close the file before you try to delete it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't have a book. I don't know how much they cost but I don't think I can afford it either way.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica Well I don't have it opened. I'm trying to delete an empty .txt file. I've got no errors or warnings but it still doesn't work :( I don't know what's wrong, I even made it so it'd need admin privliges

Comment: Yes, you do! The declaration/constructor call `std::ifstream ifile(filePath);` opens the file (if it exists). See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/).

Comment: You're right file I/O should be something simple. Unfortunately only (or FINALLY) since C++17 a cross-platform `filesystem` API is available and I definitely recommend using this, if you are using a C++17 compiler.

Comment: ` it still doesn't delete the file for some reason?`. Check the return value, and then call GetLastError. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror

Comment: @Frappy "*When I make my filePath an std::wstring, `if(!std::getline(std::cin, filePath))` tells me `no instance of overloaded function "std::getline" matches the argument list`.*" - because you need to use `std::wcin` instead. `std::cin/cout` operates on `char` data, `std::wcin/wcout` on `wchar_t` data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a mix of native Windows and standard C-style system calls, which is part of the problem. The C functions typically take `const char*` pointers, while the native windows calls use 16-bit characters (although you may be able to switch this for your compiler).

You could either use the regular C `remove()` call to delete a file, or use `DeleteFileA` Windows call which takes 8-bit characters.

Correctly converting the string from 8-bit to 16-bit is probably more of a headache than you need at this stage...

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilea

Answer (score 1):

**Cross-platform version**

Standard library of C++17 includes [filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) library from [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which works on most regular OS (MacOS, Linux, Windows). So I would definitely use it instead of Windows API.

Take a look at an [example of remove function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/remove)

Answer (score 1):

from what you say in the comments it appears you are compiling a non-Unicode version of your program. Either compile for Unicode and use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` or use the `remove` function from `stdio.h`

Take a look at it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/)

This is a pretty hackneyed topic. Some additional reading

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc

[Convert char * to LPWSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6858524/5876626)

[How to convert char* to LPCWSTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19715144/5876626)