# C++ : How to get actual folder path when the path has special folder names

Tags: c++, appdata

I am trying to find a way to convert a path like this: `"%APPDATA%\xyz\Logs\Archive"` to this: `"C:\Users\abcUser\AppData\Roaming\xyz\Logs\Archive"`.

I am on Windows platform. I use Unicode character set. I can use C++17 if required. I can use boost libraries if required.

In my search so far, I came across the [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) function. And there are StackOverflow references that explain how to resolve `%APPDATA%` to its actual path:

[How do I get the application data path in Windows using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899013/)

[C++ CreateDirectory() not working with APPDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694092/)

Comment: You could read the environment variable for APPDATA, but the best practice is to use the known folder path API to get the path. You've linked a lot of solutions but it isn't clear why none of them are working for you.

Comment: [ExpandEnvironmentStringsW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsw)

Comment: `%APPDATA%` is usually expanded by the shell, os that by the time it reaches your app (e.g. via the command line arguments) it is already expanded.

Comment: @bolov - sometimes people like to put them in configuration files for their app, then the app needs to expand them.

Comment: @davidbak yes. That's why I said "usually".

Comment: @MarkTolonen : Thanks for the reference. It worked. Add it as an answer to the question; I will select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Win32 API that expands environment variable references of the form `%variable%` in strings is [ExpandEnvironnmentStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsw).