# Wide string command line arguments in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, argv, widechar

I'm writing a program that what it does first, is to retrieve the first command line argument (which should be a process name), and find the corresponding PID of the process.

Here's how I do it:

in `main`

```
DWORD PID = FindProcessId(argv[1]);
```

and here's the function that finds PID:

```
DWORD FindProcessId(PWCHAR processname)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    PVOID buffer;
    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION spi;
    DWORD pid = 0;

    buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1024 * 1024, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    spi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)buffer;

    status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, spi, 1024 * 1024, NULL);

    while (spi->NextEntryOffset) // Loop over the list until we reach the last entry, or found PID.
    {
        if (wcsncmp(spi->ImageName.Buffer, processname, spi->ImageName.Length) == 0)
        {
            pid = spi->UniqueProcessId;
            break;
        }
        spi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)((LPBYTE)spi + spi->NextEntryOffset); // Calculate the address of the next entry.

    }

    return pid;
}
```

The thing is, it works perfectly if i simply write

`DWORD PID = FindProcessId(L"notepad.exe");`,

for example.

But when i use the command line argument and runthe program like so:
`find_pid.exe notepad.exe` the FindProcessId returns 0, meaning it didn't find the process. Even though `notepad.exe` is running like before.

Any ideas why this doesn't work with the command line argument?

---

To make the program accept `PWCHAR` rather than `char *` (Wide strings rather than ascii ones), I had to use `main` instead of `wmain`

Comment: Use a debugger to see what data you are extracting from the command line args. Or even just print the vakue. You need to learn debugging.

Comment: [Convert char * to LPWSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858524/convert-char-to-lpwstr)

Comment: But i'm passing a PWCHAR to FindProcessId, wouldn't converting the input cmd line argument cause it to misbehave?

Comment: Are you using some Windows-specific alternative version of `main()` that gets wide strings as arguments?

Comment: No `FindProcessId` expects a PWCHAR, but one is passing a `char *` if one's entry function is named `main`, it should named `wmain`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain?view=msvc-170

Comment: `while (spi->NextEntryOffset)` is wrong logic. always last process is lost. need `do { } while (spi->NextEntryOffset)`

Comment: Don't include the answer in the question, add an answer instead (and later mark it as a solution).

Comment: Why don't you just call EnumProcesses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the program accept PWCHAR rather than char * (Wide strings rather than ascii ones), I had to use wmain instead of main, like so:

```
int wmain(int argc, PWCHAR argv[])
{
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

OR

Just convert the `char *` to a `wide string - PWCHAR`, like so:

```
WCHAR victimProcessName[MAX_PATH];
mbstowcs(victimProcessName, argv[1], MAX_PATH); // Plus null
```