# c++ 'CA2W': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi

why do i get 'CA2W': identifier not found

```
for(DWORD i = 0; i < numMaterials; i++)    // for each material...
    {
        material[i] = tempMaterials[i].MatD3D;    // get the material info
        material[i].Ambient = material[i].Diffuse;    // make ambient the same as diffuse
        USES_CONVERSION;    // allows certain string conversions
        // if there is a texture to load, load it
        D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(d3ddev,
                                            CA2W(tempMaterials[i].pTextureFilename),
                                            &texture[i]);
        texture[i] = NULL;    // if there is no texture, set the texture to NULL
      }
```

Comment: Like I said a bit ago, you really need to start over and learn *just* C++. Learn really good, solid, clean, basic C++, then move upwards, *then* try game programming. Game programming isn't trivial, and you can't really get anywhere if you're trying to learn idiomatic C++ at the same time. Really, I think we'd all like to see you get better, but we really can't do much more. At some point you have to take it upon yourself to take the time to really learn the fundamentals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Edit:

The OP has just told me that Visual Studio 2010 Express was used to compile the code. That would explain why `CA2W` couldn't be found, because the Express editions do not include the entire ATL/MFC library. Therefore, my original answer is irrelevant to the OP.

**The moral of the story: make sure to mention exactly what environment you're on when asking these kinds of questions.**

Instead of using `CA2W`, you can use [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072.aspx) - this function is what's actually being used by `CA2W` to convert the string, so you'll get basically the same result.

[Here's a usage example of `MultiByteToWideChar()` in an answer to another Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcwstr-in-c-unicode/27296#27296). It's for a conversion from `std::string` to `LPCWSTR`, but it's basically the same process.

### Original answer:

According to [the documentation for ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28VS.80%29.aspx) you must include:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

int main()
{ 
    // Explicitly qualified the CA2W identifier
    ATL::CA2W("Hello World!"); // Test to see if this compiles
}
```

I think the reason why this code snippet didn't work before was because you `#define`'d `_ATL_NO_AUTOMATIC_NAMESPACE` somewhere before `#include <atlbase.h>`.

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: Yes. You can use the `MultiByteToWideChar()` function found in the Windows SDK.

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: You can find usage examples of `MultiByteToWideChar()` right here on Stack overflow, as well as on other sites. If you have problems with using the function, I highly suggest asking another question, so I don't clutter my answer any more than it is.

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: Here's an example of `MultiByteToWideChar()` on Stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcwstr-in-c-unicode

Comment: @Insilico, you said in the other answer that including `atlconv.h` should be enough. Why do you also include `atlbase.h`? For some reason, in my case I just need to include the latter - and if I only include the former, the code does not compile. Which is weird because the [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ca2wex-class?view=vs-2019) it's in the `atlconv` header.

Answer (score 3):

Show us your code, otherwise we are powerless to help you.

The error you are getting means: "What the heck is CA2W???"

It means you are using the identifier CA2W, but it hasn't been declared as anything.

Comment: ok i gave you where is the error is happening

Comment: @Ramiz: The code above doesn't change the answer. The compiler simply doesn't know what CA2W is.

Comment: ok but how should i know where ca2w can be found

Comment: i checked out the msdn and they said to include atlconv.h  but it still can't find it

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: If you don't know what `CA2W` is, why are you using it in the code? This is no different from if you typed some gibberish in the code, like `jcgdhfgdh`, and then started asking why the compiler doesn't know what it is.

Comment: i know what it does from the tutorial that i read and i copied their code

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: So you basically copied-and-pasted code without bothering to understand what it does?

Comment: the function changes it from LPSTR to LPCWSTR

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: Well, if you know what it is, then you should know where it is supposed to come from: library or such. A library, for example, will supply you with a header file that will contain the declaration of `CA2W`. You have to `#include` that header in your code.

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: It is in fact not a function. It's a typedef to a `CA2WEX` class. Basically you're constructing a temporary `CA2WEX` that performs the conversion. Including `atlconv.h` should be sufficient to solve the problem since it's defined there. The fact that it still doesn't work (as you mentioned in another answer) means we need more information (like say, compiler errors).

Comment: well i have atlconv.h defined

Comment: Error 5 error C3861: 'CA2W': identifier not found c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\monopoly\monopoly\monopoly.cpp 170

Answer (score 3):

So try this - Create a Win32 console project, then replace the given code with this below that compiles fine for me. If this does not compile for you, I'm stumped - perhaps re-install Visual Studio? Seems like multiple people can compile this properly, so what might be wrong with your Visual Studio installation?

```
// testconv.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlconv.h>
#include <atlbase.h> 
#include <atlstr.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   USES_CONVERSION;
   WCHAR *pChar = CA2W(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`CA2W` is defined in `<atlconv.h>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsyac802%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: i did that but it didn't work

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: Care to tell us how it didn't work? Did you get a compiler error? What was the error(s), if any?

Comment: Error 5 error C3861: 'CA2W': identifier not found c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\monopoly\monopoly\monopoly.cpp 170

Answer (score 0):

Check if the path to the ATL header files `atlconv.h` and `atlbase.h` is visible to Visual Studio

In your monopoly.cpp file, right-click on the line `#include <atlconv.h>` and select **Open document atlconv.h**. If the header file opens properly, then it means there is no problem with the location. Instead, if it throws an error, then it means VStudio cannot locate the file and that's the reason why it says 'identifier not found'.

In the error message, VStudio displays the path to the folders where it looked for the header file. Check if the list contains a path similar to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include", where the ATL header files are present. If it is missing, include the path (use the path appropriate to your OS and the version of VStudio that you are using) as follows: Visual Studio: Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Directories-> "Show directories for Include files".