# C string to wide C string assignment

Tags: c++, string, cstring

I'm a little confused about C strings and wide C strings. For the sake of this question, assume that I using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional. Please let me know if any of my information is incorrect.

I have a struct with a const wchar_t* member which is used to store a name.

```
struct A
{
    const wchar_t* name;
};
```

When I assign object 'a' a name as so:

```
int main()
{
    A a;

    const wchar_t* w_name = L"Tom";
    a.name = w_name;

    return 0;
}
```

That is just copying the memory address that w_name points to into a.name. Now w_name and a.name are both wide character pointers which point to the same address in memory.

If I am correct, then I am wondering what to do about a situation like this. I am reading in a C string from an XML attribute using tinyxml2.

```
tinyxml2::XMLElement* pElement;
// ...
const char* name = pElement->Attribute("name");
```

After I have my C string, I am converting it to a wide character string as follows:

```
size_t newsize = strlen(name) + 1;
wchar_t * wcName = new wchar_t[newsize];
size_t convertedChars = 0;
mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcName, newsize, name, _TRUNCATE);

a.name = wcName;

delete[] wcName;
```

If I am correct so far, then the line:

```
 a.name = wcName;
```

is just copying the memory address of the first character of array wcName into a.name. However, I am deleting wcName directly after assigning this pointer which would make it point to garbage.

How can I convert my C string into a wide character C string and then assign it to a.name?

Comment: Why are you deleting wcName?  If the point is to convert to wchar_t, then why are you deleting the newly-allocated memory holding the result of your conversion?

Comment: The code as posted is problematic. There doesn't seem to be an ideal place to delete it. I thought about adding an ~A() destructor to delete it, but that seems really ugly to me for some reason.

Comment: @user974967 That (the destructor) is *precisely* where you would delete it (or anytime you need to reassign it, but then I would advise trying to reuse the buffer if the new assignment still fits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is probably to task you `name` variable with the management of the memory. This, in turn, is easily done by declaring it as

```
std::wstring name;
```

These guys don't have a concept of independent content and object mutation, i.e., you can't really make the individual characters `const` and making the entire object `const` would prevent it from being assigned to.

Comment: But how is this going to get his conversion done? Granted it would save him from having to manage the out-of-scope deletion of his conversion buffer, which is currently deleted incorrectly after saving the address. Or did the std lib add a `char*` to `std::wstring` up-conversion and I missed it (wouldn't be the first time I was sleeping at the wheel).

Comment: It seems he is already doing the conversion using `mbstowc()` (well the "safe" abomination `mbstowcs_s()` which a certain vendor tries to impose). Whether this deals correctly with whatever encoding is in the XML file, I don't know, but it seems that the question wasn't about the conversion.

Comment: @WhozCraig - using a `wstring` will make `a.name = wcName;` work correctly, and the temp buffer can be deleted afterwards without problems.

Comment: @BoPersson or use the std::wstring *as* the buffer itself. (see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405176/c-string-to-wide-c-string-assignment/13406143#13406143))

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this while using a `std::wstring` without relying on the additional temporary conversion buffer allocation and destruction. Not tremendously important unless you're overtly concerned about heap fragmentation or on a limited system (aka Windows Phone). It just takes a little setup on the front side. Let the standard library manage the memory for you (with a little nudge).

```
class A
{
   ...
   std::wstring a;
};


// Convert the string (I'm assuming it is UTF8) to wide char
int wlen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, name, -1, NULL, NULL);
if (wlen > 0)
{
    // reserve space. std::wstring gives us the terminator slot
    // for free, so don't include that. MB2WC above returns the
    // length *including* the terminator.
    a.resize(wlen-1);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, name, -1, &a[0], wlen);
}
else
{   // no conversion available/possible.
    a.clear();
}
```

On a complete side-note, you *can* build TinyXML to use the standard library and `std::string` rather than `char *`, which doesn't really help you much here, but may save you a *ton* of future `strlen()` calls later on.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly mentioned `a.name` is just a pointer which doesn't suppose any allocated string storage. You must manage it manually using `new` or static/scoped array.

To get rid of these boring things just use one of available string classes: `CStringW` from ATL (easy to use but MS-specific) or `std::wstring` from STL (C++ standard, but not so easy to convert from `char*`):

```
#include <atlstr.h>

// Conversion ANSI -> Wide is automatic
const CStringW name(pElement->Attribute("name"));
```

Unfortunately, `std::wstring` usage with `char*` is not so easy.
See conversion functon here: [How to convert std::string to LPCWSTR in C++ (Unicode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcwstr-in-c-unicode)