# How do I convert a string to a wstring using the value of the string?

Tags: c++, string, wstring

I'm new to C++ and I have this issue. I have a string called DATA_DIR that I need for format into a wstring.

```
string str = DATA_DIR;
std::wstring temp(L"%s",str);
```

Visual Studio tells me that there is no instance of constructor that matches with the argument list. Clearly, I'm doing something wrong.

I found this example online

```
std::wstring someText( L"hello world!" );
```

which apparently works (no compile errors). My question is, how do I get the string value stored in DATA_DIR into the wstring constructor as opposed to something arbitrary like "hello world"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert std::string to LPCWSTR in C++ (Unicode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcwstr-in-c-unicode)

Comment: Check out http://www.utf8everywhere.org/ and consider using the boost::nowide library provided on that page to convert string to wstring and back.  Makes life much easier :)

Comment: What is the encoding of the text in the `string`?  Usually either ISO/IEC 8859-1 (Which many incorrectly call "ASCII") or UTF-8.

Comment: Please see my edit below. My original code had a big mistake in it.

Answer (score 7):

This is in reference to the most up-voted answer but I don't have enough "reputation" to just comment directly on the answer.

The name of the function in the solution "wstring_from_bytes" implies it is doing what the original poster wants, which is to get a wstring given a string, but the function is actually doing the opposite of what the original poster asked for and would more accurately be named "bytes_from_wstring".

To convert from string to wstring, the wstring_from_bytes function should use mbstowcs not wcstombs

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

std::wstring wstring_from_bytes(std::string const& str)
{
    size_t requiredSize = 0;
    std::wstring answer;
    wchar_t *pWTempString = NULL;

    /*
    * Call the conversion function without the output buffer to get the required size
    *  - Add one to leave room for the NULL terminator
    */
    requiredSize = mbstowcs(NULL, str.c_str(), 0) + 1;

    /* Allocate the output string (Add one to leave room for the NULL terminator) */  
    pWTempString = (wchar_t *)malloc( requiredSize * sizeof( wchar_t ));  
    if (pWTempString == NULL)  
    {  
        printf("Memory allocation failure.\n");  
    }
    else
    {
        // Call the conversion function with the output buffer
        size_t size = mbstowcs( pWTempString, str.c_str(), requiredSize);
        if (size == (size_t) (-1))  
        {  
            printf("Couldn't convert string\n");  
        }
        else
        {
            answer = pWTempString;
        }
    }


    if (pWTempString != NULL)
    {
        delete[] pWTempString;
    }

    return answer;
}

int main()
{
   std::string str = "abcd";
   std::wstring wstr = wstring_from_bytes(str);
}
```

Regardless, this is much more easily done in newer versions of the standard library (C++ 11 and newer)

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;

std::wstring wide = converter.from_bytes(narrow_utf8_source_string);
```

Comment: The C++11 portion of the answer worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is an implementation using `wcstombs` (Updated):

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <cstdlib>
> #include <string>
>  
> std::string wstring_from_bytes(std::wstring const& wstr)
> {
>     std::size_t size = sizeof(wstr.c_str());
>     char *str = new char[size];
>     std::string temp;
>  
>     std::wcstombs(str, wstr.c_str(), size);
>
>     temp = str;
>     delete[] str;
>  
>     return temp;
> }
>  
> int main()
> {
>     std::wstring wstr = L"abcd";
>     std::string str = wstring_from_bytes(wstr);
> }
> ```

[Here is a demo.](http://ideone.com/y3OLOa#view_edit_box)

Comment: This is funny! First `sizeof()` does not give you the length of the string, you have `strlen` or `wcslen` for that. Second, you didn't check for `empty()`. Third, you converted the other way around. And last but not least, you leaked the `str ` pointer in your linked example. 

Comment: I was new to this stuff back then :)

Answer (score 4):

`printf`-style format specifiers are not part of the C++ library and cannot be used to construct a `string`.

If the `string` may only contain single-byte characters, then the range constructor is sufficient.

```
std::string narrower( "hello" );
std::wstring wider( narrower.begin(), narrower.end() );
```

The problem is that we usually use `wstring` when wide characters are applicable (hence the `w`), which are represented in `std::string` by multibyte sequences. Doing this will cause each byte of a multibyte sequence to translate to an sequence of incorrect wide characters.

Moreover, to convert a multibyte sequence requires knowing its encoding. This information is not encapsulated by `std::string` nor `std::wstring`. C++11 allows you to specify an encoding and translate using `std::wstring_convert`, but I'm not sure how widely supported it is of yet. See 0x....'s excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

The converter mentioned for C++11 and above has deprecated this specific conversion in C++17, and suggests using the MultiByteToWideChar function.

The compiler error (c4996) mentions defining _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING.

Comment: How does this answer the question? I think this would be better as a comment under the relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
wstring temp = L"";
for (auto c : DATA_DIR)
   temp.push_back(c);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this function. Could not find any predefined method to do this.

```
std::wstring s2ws(const std::string& s)
{
    int len;
    int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
    len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
    wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
    std::wstring r(buf);
    delete[] buf;
    return r;
}

std::wstring stemp = s2ws(myString);
```

Comment: This is not using the standard library. It looks like Win32.

Comment: Yea, its not using standard library. Asker is using Visual Studio. It can be of help if he is using WINAPI.

Comment: And what exactly does `CP_ACP` do? It appears to specify the a system-defined, non-multibyte encoding. This API makes it very difficult to write portably.

Comment: CP_ACP is to define the codepage when MultiByteToWideChar performs the conversion. CP_ACP defines it to be ANSI codepage.

Comment: And "ANSI codepage" is an ill-defined concept that is likely not to be what he wants.

Comment: I just answered what I used and what worked for me. It asker finds its working then its fine, and if not then other answers are also there using standard libraries.

Comment: Very often, insufficient testing (e.g. using only one machine or similar machines) allows poorly internationalized code to ship because problems only show up for foreign encodings. These days UTF-8 is a better choice than ISO 8859. Generally speaking, ANSI stands for *American* National Standards Institute, and they have no motive or authority to make standards regarding *international* communication, besides which Microsoft often abuses their name in an attempt to present their proprietary solutions as the "business standard." See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page : CP_ACP is not ANSI.

Comment: Not usable out of the box, the answer needs better annotation/explanation.