# Unicode string visual c++ constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, unicode

So, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with project settings set to "use unicode".

I have this included to my file:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

And when i try to do this

```
 //process.szExeFile - WCHAR[260]
 //name - PCSTR
if (string(process.szExeFile) == string(name))
```

Visual studio throws an error C2665.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the actual error text?

Comment: error C2665: std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::basic_string: none of the 17 overloads can convert parameters

Comment: try `wstring(process.szExeFile)`

Comment: says it cant do the operation 
std::wstring == PCSTR

Comment: @BerNardEr: That's because `PCSTR` is unrelated to `WCHAR[]`. You need to understand the difference between 8 and 16 bit characters in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

When the project is set to "use unicode", the `process.szExeFile` field is of type `WCHAR[]`.  The `std::string` class does not provide a constructor which accepts `WCHAR[]` (or `wchar_t*`) as input.

You are comparing a `name` variable as a non-Unicode string, so I assume you don't care about non-ASCII characters.  If that is true, you may do this:

```
std::wstring exeStr(process.szExeFile);
std::string exeStrA(exeStr.begin(), exeStr.end());
if (exeStrA == string(name))
```

If you care about non-ASCII characters, you should do it the other way around, converting your `name` string to Unicode, for example using `wsctombs()` (you can find an example here: [How do I convert a string to a wstring using the value of the string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244133/)).

Comment: Thanks, i really haven't thought about it.