# Expression: string iterators incompatiable, when calling "SetDllDirectory"

Tags: c++, wstring, lpcwstr, setdlldirectory

I'm receiving following error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Expression: string iterators incompatible

When trying to run such a code:

```
std::string string_Dir(){return ".\\Dir\\";}
std::wstring wstring_Dir=std::wstring(
    string_Dir().begin()
    ,string_Dir().end()
    );
SetDllDirectory(wstring_Dir.c_str());
```

Does someone know why

BTW: I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139684/4838962).

Comment: Because `string` != `wstring`, because `char` != `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `string_Dir()` twice and then using iterators from *different* `std::string` objects to initialize your `std::wstring`.  That is why you are getting an incompatibility error.  You must use iterators from the *same* `std::string` object, so call `string_Dir()` once and assign the return value to a variable:

```
std::string dir = string_Dir();
std::wstring wstring_Dir(dir.begin(), dir.end());
SetDllDirectory(wstring_Dir.c_str());
// or better: SetDllDirectoryW(wstring_Dir.c_str());
```

That being said, you are not converting from ANSI to UTF-16, so this code will only work correctly if `string_Dir()` returns a `std::string` that contains *only* 7bit ASCII characters. It will fail if the `std::string` contains any non-ASCII 8bit characters.

There is a simpler solution - you can call `SetDllDirectoryA()` instead.  You don't need the `std::wstring`, and the OS can do the ANSI-to-UTF16 conversion for you:

```
SetDllDirectoryA(string_Dir().c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the value in the function call is supposed to be `LPCTSTR` instead of `LPCTWSTR`.

Comment: I'm using UNICODE `#ifdef UNICODE
#define SetDllDirectory  SetDllDirectoryW`

Comment: @user4838962 "To compile an application that uses this function, define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0502 or later." Have you done this as well?

Comment: @user4838962 Also, wouldn't you call `SetDllDirectoryW`instead of `SetDllDirectory`

Comment: @JeffS: Since `UNICODE` is defined, `SetDllDirectory()` maps to `SetDllDirectoryW()`.  But since `std::wstring` is being used, it is better to call `SetDllDirectoryW()` directly and not rely on `TCHAR` mapping at all.