# convert a STRING from LPCWSTR and vice versa c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, lpcwstr

I want to compare a LPCWSTR with a value to ensure they're equal. And I can't figure out how to compare it. I create a STRING value and tried various conversions but nothing worked. Essentially it would be:

```
request->id // some LPCWSTR value
STRING str = "value" // String value I want to compare
if (request->id != str)
{
 //Something
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lpcwstr-in-c-unicode

Comment: what is `STRING`?

Answer (score 1):

Enable MFC/ATL and use the CString object:

```
if (CString(request->id) != str)
```

Although it's not clear to me what type STRING is either.  I would just use CString for both:

```
STRING str = "value" // String value I want to compare
if (CString(request->id) != str)
```

Or just use the literal directly:

```
if (CString(request->id) != "value")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [std::wstring](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) type instead of a std::string in which case you have the `.c_str()` member function to work with or copy the string to a buffer using the [MultiByteToWideChar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI function.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it to work using this process.

LPCWSTR lpc = L"STRING";
wcscmp(LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR)